# How to return a matplot chart in excel using xlwing and Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, xlwings

I'm new to Python and Xlwings. I am trying to create a UDF to return a "BOX plot" in excel. Table in Excel has two columns "Sales_Region" and "Total Sales".

On running the below code, I am getting the error "Object required". I think the error is basically due to incorrect usage of decorators. Looking for help!

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame



@xw.func
@xw.arg('df', pd.DataFrame, index = False, header=True)
@xw.arg('x_name', category = str)
@xw.arg('y_name', category = str)

def BOX_Plot(df,x_name,y_name):

    dt = pd.DataFrame(df)
    names = x_name
    bill =  y_name


    sns.set_style("whitegrid")
    ax = sns.boxplot(x=names, y=bill, data=dt)

    medians = dt.groupby([names])[bill].median().values
    median_labels = [str(np.round(s, 2)) for s in medians]

    pos = range(len(medians))
    for tick,label in zip(pos,ax.get_xticklabels()):
        ax.text(pos[tick], medians[tick], median_labels[tick], 
                horizontalalignment='center', size='x-small', color='w', weight='semibold')

    plt.show()

    return "Done!"
```

Comment: Issue is solved, I forgot to add the Xlwings reference in the VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was perfect, I forgot to add the Xlwings reference in the VBA tool.